# get variable in php leading to database not accepted

Tags: php, mysql

so i have this php code :

```
session_start();
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$dbname = "3890ask3_db";


$con = mysql_connect($servername, $username, "", $dbname)
  or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

  $db=mysql_select_db($dbname,$con) 
  or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());  

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM register where Username = '$_SESSION[Username]'") or die(mysql_error()); 
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());

    if(isset($_GET['selecttoy']))
    {
   $clname=$row['Name'];
   $clsurname=$row['Surname'];
   $clemail=$row['Email'];
   $stoy=$_GET['selecttoy'];


   $query2 = "INSERT INTO order (ClName, ClSurname, ClEmail, ToyCode , OrderID) VALUES ('$clname', '$clsurname', '$clemail' , '$stoy', ' ' )" ;
  if (mysql_query($query2)) {
    echo "Order created successfully!";
} else {
    echo "Error: "  . "<br>" . mysql_error($con);
 }
}

?>
```

The php page can actually read the get variable,but as soon as i try to insert something in the database, i get this error message:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (ClName, ClSurname, ClEmail, ToyCode , OrderID) VALUES ('mar', 'kyr', 'dgg' at line 1"

i tried everything but no result...can someone please help me?
thanks in advance....

Comment: [`order`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) is a MySQL reserved word.... if you want to use it as a table name, you have to enclose it in backticks (`)

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks...that was the mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `order` directly because it's reserved word. try to enclose it in (``). Like below:-

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO `order` (ClName, ClSurname, ClEmail, ToyCode , OrderID) VALUES ('$clname', '$clsurname', '$clemail' , '$stoy', ' ' )" ;
```

Note:- **Try to add `sql error reporting code` always.**

**stop using `mysql_*`, use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.**

**your above code is open for `SQL Injection`. thanks.**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions...i'll keep them in mind

Comment: If it work then try to mark as an answer. thanks. Also i think its valuable to you.